# to_numpy not returning float in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe wji that is created and I want to convert it to a float. When I run to_numpy it converts my dataframe as a 2D array as expected by the dtype is not float and is actually object. I thought to_numpy converted to a float

```
print(wji)
wji = wji.to_numpy()
wji.astype(float)
print(wji.dtype)
print(wji)

               0          1          2          3
m00     0.265211   0.181399   0.111651 -0.0847051
mu02   -0.028225  0.0962054   0.113064  -0.213155
mu11  -0.0357038   0.208511  0.0182606   0.320326
mu20    0.351853  -0.161808  -0.129546  0.0154996
mu03  -0.0295777   -0.32005    0.27918  -0.252604
mu12    0.289506   0.176424   0.327829   0.309716
mu21 -0.00807781  0.0486644  -0.266619   0.211797
mu30    0.260602  -0.222457   0.044188  0.0241173
object
[[0.2652110197196954 0.18139929673003075 0.11165104327710718
  -0.08470512466140445]
 [-0.02822495204464942 0.09620543158200529 0.11306380462982002
  -0.21315489965597814]
 [-0.03570382418488832 0.20851099678961427 0.018260584909711663
  0.3203261779270866]
 [0.3518532632204968 -0.16180755912222522 -0.12954580116058592
  0.015499553874823824]
 [-0.02957772808836734 -0.3200497237343074 0.279179861454914
  -0.2526041954889673]
 [0.2895059792721121 0.17642419095938044 0.3278292712959946
  0.30971597348796753]
 [-0.008077807534792092 0.04866444048641794 -0.2666191448153845
  0.21179737334015403]
 [0.26060214043724306 -0.22245697799194314 0.044188046165909045
  0.02411734493263573]]
```

Comment: What's `wji`?  A pandas dataframe?  If so correct the tags.

Comment: yes it is a pandas dataframe but shouldn't to_numpy return a float?

Comment: What is `wji.dtypes` or `wji.info()`?

Comment: can you provide code to preproduce this? The above is output, not code. I start an answer and we can refine it into running code

Comment: `wji.astype(float)` returns a new dataframe or `ndarray`; it does not change `wji` itself.

Answer (score 0):

`wji.astype(float)` does not change wji's type.
Try this.

Change `wji.astype(float)` to `wji = wji.astype(float)`